# Как сохранить массив в бд

Tags: php, mysqli

```
$file = file("P1802FAT_2017-02-19_08.55.11.dat");
foreach ($file as $value) {
$arr = explode(":", $value);
$sql = "INSERT INTO dat (beginheader, clk, typ, starttime, frames, starttrigger, stoptrigger, pda_reftimestamp, module_name_0, module_name_1, module_name_2, module_name_3, module_name_4, module_name_5, module_name_6, module_name_7, version, pdakeyinfo, pdakeyinfo2, pdadongleId, beginchannel, name, unit, pda_comment1, digchannel, pda_tbase, pda_typ, minscale, maxscale, xoffset, channel_offset, endchannel, endascii) VALUES ('$arr[1]')";
if (mysqli_query($link, $sql)) {
    echo "Запись успешно сохранена.";
} else {
    echo "Ошибка: Не удалось выполнить $sql. " . mysqli_error($link);
}
```

}

В браузере:

Ошибка: Не удалось выполнить INSERT INTO dat (beginheader, clk, typ, starttime, frames, starttrigger, stoptrigger, pda_reftimestamp, module_name_0, module_name_1, module_name_2, module_name_3, module_name_4, module_name_5, module_name_6, module_name_7, version, pdakeyinfo, pdakeyinfo2, pdadongleId, beginchannel, name, unit, pda_comment1, digchannel, pda_tbase, pda_typ, minscale, maxscale, xoffset, channel_offset, endchannel, endascii) VALUES ('
'). Column count doesn't match value count at row 1Ошибка: Не удалось выполнить INSERT INTO dat (beginheader, clk, typ, starttime, frames, starttrigger, stoptrigger, pda_reftimestamp, module_name_0, module_name_1, module_name_2, module_name_3, module_name_4, module_name_5, module_name_6, module_name_7, version, pdakeyinfo, pdakeyinfo2, pdadongleId, beginchannel, name, unit, pda_comment1, digchannel, pda_tbase, pda_typ, minscale, maxscale, xoffset, channel_offset, endchannel, endascii) VALUES ('0.01
').

Comment: Попробуйте VALUES (" . implode(', ', $arr) . ")"

Comment: не работает, пишет 'You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near' ? как я понял он ругнулся VALUES (" . implode(', ', $arr) . ")" , но синтаксической ошибки не было

Comment: Попробуйте для начала распечатать запрос: print_r($sql), не делая запрос к базе. Вы увидите какой запрос отправляется.

Comment: сделал распечатку получается что в VALUES (typ, real) то есть ключ значения.
'INSERT INTO dat (beginheader,clk, float, typ, starttime, frames, starttrigger, stoptrigger, pda_reftimestamp, module_name_0, module_name_1, module_name_2, module_name_3, module_name_4, module_name_5, module_name_6, module_name_7, version, pdakeyinfo, pdakeyinfo2, pdadongleid, endheader, beginchannel, name, unit, pda_comment1, digchannel, pda_tbase, pda_typ, minscale, maxscale, xoffset, channel_offset, endchannel, endascii) VALUES (typ, real
)'

Comment: а у меня VALUES('$arr[1]') 1 это уже значение

Comment: Сделайте print_r($arr) и посмотрите что в нём. Возможно первая строка в файле это заголовки

Comment: Сделал print_r($arr)
Array
(
    [0] => typ
    [1] => real

)

Comment: А остальные строки? Или в файле только одна строка?

Comment: файл большой, и он в строку, я делаю из него массив и хочу сохранить в бд. Но не получается?

Comment: вот сам файл https://fex.net/s/9xsbt62 открывать в notepad++

Comment: 1. Вы неправильно проанализировали файл. Он не в строку, там просто переносы строку в другой системе. 2. С 1 по 21 строку идёт header(beginheader - endheader). Дальше повторяются только chanel(beginchannel - endchannel). После 2890 строки в файле каша.

Comment: После 2890 строки мне не нужно, мне надо вытащить beginheader - endheader и beginchannel - endchannel

Comment: то есть получается что мой код не правильный??

Comment: 1. У Вас в каждом элементе массива получается отдельное значение. 2. В базе нужны две таблицы (одна для header другая для chanel). Потому что у них разные поля.

Comment: а я все в одной таблицы сделал, так это не суть, проблема в том что не могу сохранить в бд

Comment: так правильно вытащить инфу в бд???

Answer (score 1):

Вы пытаетесь присвоить всем, или не всем полям в БД какое-то значение. MySQL не поддерживает хранение массивов. Сейчас у вас такой запрос(условно):

Присвой полям(имя, фамилия, отчество) значения(array), MySQL видит это так:

```
имя => array,
фамилия => Мне ничего не присвоили, выкину ошибку :(
отчество => Мне ничего не присвоили, выикину ошибку :(
```

У вас есть массив полей `INSERT INTO dat (beginheader, clk,...)` и должен быть **соответствующий** массив значений `VALUES('someinfo', '123', ...)`. Так как вы используете "голый" sql-запрос, а не пользуетесь PDO - то могу предложить вам использовать следующий код:

```
$file = file("P1802FAT_2017-02-19_08.55.11.dat");

foreach ($file as $value) {
    $arr = explode(":", $value); // тут мы получили массив значений из строки

    $sql = "INSERT INTO dat (beginheader, clk, typ, starttime, frames, starttrigger, 
    stoptrigger, pda_reftimestamp, module_name_0, module_name_1, module_name_2, 
    module_name_3, module_name_4, module_name_5, module_name_6, module_name_7, version, 
    pdakeyinfo, pdakeyinfo2, pdadongleId, beginchannel, name, unit, pda_comment1, 
    digchannel, pda_tbase, pda_typ, minscale, maxscale, xoffset, channel_offset, 
    endchannel, endascii)";

    $values = implode(',', $arr) // тут мы "склеили" все значения в строку

    $sql .= " VALUES({$values})" // и тут просто дополнили наш sql-запрос

    if (mysqli_query($link, $sql)) {
        echo "Запись успешно сохранена.";
    } else {
        echo "Ошибка: Не удалось выполнить $sql. " . mysqli_error($link);
    }
}
```

**НАПОМНЮ**, что количество полей и количетсво значений **ДОЛЖНО совпадать**.

Об методе [implode](https://www.php.net/manual/ru/function.implode.php)

Comment: "Ошибка: Не удалось выполнить INSERT INTO dat (beginheader, .......  endascii) VALUES(beginheader,).You have an error in your SQL syntax

Когда делаю print_r($values); получаю --> "beginheader, ". В $arr[1] тут у меня значение, а  $arr[0] просто ключ который есть в таблицы в заголовках.
Причина тому как я думаю, выше в комментариях скидывал сам файл, в самом файле есть строчка endASCII: вот все что до этой строчки мне надо в бд, а после меня не интересует, там нету инфы, кракозябры.

Comment: Напишите полный текст ошибки.

Comment: Ошибка: Не удалось выполнить INSERT INTO dat (beginheader.... endascii) VALUES(beginheader,). You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ')' at line 7
Ошибка: Не удалось выполнить INSERT INTO dat (beginheader.... endascii) VALUES(clk,0.01). Column count doesn't match value count at row 1Ошибка: Не удалось выполнить INSERT INTO dat (beginheader.... endascii) VALUES(typ,real). You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use

Comment: У вас все та же самая ошибка, вы пытаетесь присвоить определенному количеству полей одно значение, количество элементов в скобках `..dat()` должно совпадать с количеством элементов, описываемых в `...VALUES()`. Парсить информацию из файла можно, вы это и делаете, но вы должны убедиться что вы правильно пользуетесь функцией `explode()`, вам возвращает `beginheader`, потому что explode смотрит строку, переданную ему, и первое значение в массив попадает ВСЕ символы до первого символа `:` - убедитесь что вы правильно парсите файл

Comment: В начале я вызываю функцию file, после сам файл уже становиться массивом..

Array
(
    [0] => ��� beginheader:

    [1] => clk:0.01

    [2] => typ:real

    [3] => .....:.....

Потом идет foreach ($file as $value), за ним следует функция explode $arr = explode(":", $value) и в VALUES я должен вставить $arr[1], где один это значение а 0 это ключ. Но есть одно но, в конце массива есть последний ключ endASCII:  , вот до этого ключа мне надо сохранять, а за ним нет, но у меня происходит наоборот, пытается все сохранить, вот и поэтому идет ошибка с определенным количеством полей

Comment: Уберите последний элемент из массива `unset($arr[count($arr)-1])`

Comment: после explode добавил и в VALUES(тут ключи а не значения)

Comment: сделал по своему 

    $arr = explode(":", $value);
    unset($arr[count($arr)-1]);
    $sql = "INSERT INTO dat (beginheader, ..... endascii) VALUES ('$arr[1]', .... '$arr[1]')";
    if (mysqli_query($link, $sql)) {
        echo "Запись успешно сохранена.";
    } else {
        echo "Ошибка: Не удалось выполнить $sql. " . mysqli_error($link);

Ошибка в браузере
Notice:  Undefined offset: 1 in /var/www/html/reg/index.php on line 153
153 это как раз $sql = "INSERT INTO dat 
Если в значениях оставить 1 массив, то будет Column count doesn't match value count at row 1

Comment: Вы пытаетесь обратиться к массиву `$arr[1]`, в котором не существует элемента с индексом 1, потому что скорее всего у вас в цикле `foreach` доходит до конца и в конце в переменную `$value` попадает одно значение и после `explode` остается массив `['some_value_here']` у элемента которого индекс равен `0`

Comment: 1. И что мне делать.
2. Можно как то циклом вытащить всю инфу до endASCII, ну он у меня уже в массиве без explode, ну типа [2] => typ:real, потому что с тем мусором который начинается после endASCII: покоя не дает???

Comment: Загрузите файл на pastebin и оставьте ссылку на него в комментариях. Нужно увидеть что именно в нем.

Comment: Я тут штуку заметил, создал новую таб и там два поля 'clc' и 'typ', код $sql = "INSERT INTO don (clk, typ) VALUES ('$arr[1]','$arr[1]')"; ошибка
INSERT INTO don (clk, typ) VALUES ('','')
Ошибка: Не удалось выполнить INSERT INTO don (clk, typ) VALUES ('',''). 
Incorrect integer value: '' for column 'clk' at row 1INSERT INTO don (clk, typ) VALUES ('0.01','0.01')Запись успешно сохранена.INSERT INTO don (clk, typ) VALUES ('real','real').
Ошибка: Не удалось выполнить INSERT INTO don (clk, typ) VALUES ('real','real'). Incorrect integer value: 'real' for column 'clk' at row 1

че за бред?

Comment: Вы мучаетесь с одной и той же проблемой. У вас банальное не совпадение типов и количества (полей=>значений)

Comment: и как мне ее решить то???

Comment: может через pdo попробовать?

Comment: Попробуйте, только внимательно изучите информацию про запросы.